# County Dissimilarity Indices using R package "Segregation"

Tags: r, spatial, census, tidycensus

When I use the following code, the estimate (dissimilarity, D) is the same for all Counties (0.648). I'm wondering if it has to do with lack of geometry information, since I created the County_FIPS variable. Looking for suggestions on how to fix this code or do the operation differently. The goal is dissimilarity indices for all counties in the U.S. I ran a batch of half the states first to reduce the size/time it took.
(Beginner/Intermediate User)

```
my_states <- c("AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "DC", "FL", "GA", "HI",
               "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", "MD", "MA", "MI")

#my_states2 <- c ("MN", "MS", "MO", "MT", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ", "NM", "NY", 
               "NC", "ND", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", "RI", "SC", "SD", "TN", "TX",
               "UT", "VT", "VA", "WA", "WV", "WI", "WY") 

acs_data1 <- get_acs(
  geography = "tract",
  variables = c(
    white = "B03002_003",
    black = "B03002_004",
    asian = "B03002_006",
    hispanic = "B03002_012"), 
  state = my_states,
  geometry = TRUE,
  year = 2019
) 

seg_acs_data <- acs_data1 %>% 
  mutate(COUNTY_FIPS = substr(GEOID, 1, 5))

subsetseg <- seg_acs_data %>% filter(variable %in% c("white", "black"))
  
dissimilarity <- subsetseg %>% group_by(COUNTY_FIPS) %>%
  group_modify(~
                 dissimilarity(data = subsetseg,
                               group = "variable",
                               unit = "GEOID",
                               weight = "estimate"
                 ))
```

--
Without saving the output as an object ("dissimilarity") the output is:

```
# A tibble: 1,314 x 3
# Groups:   COUNTY_FIPS [1,314]
   COUNTY_FIPS stat    est
   <chr>       <chr> <dbl>
 1 01001       D     0.648
 2 01003       D     0.648
 3 01005       D     0.648
 4 01007       D     0.648
 5 01009       D     0.648
 6 01011       D     0.648
 7 01013       D     0.648
 8 01015       D     0.648
 9 01017       D     0.648
10 01019       D     0.648
# ... with 1,304 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the relevant section of your code here:

```
             dissimilarity(data = subsetseg,
                           group = "variable",
                           unit = "GEOID",
                           weight = "estimate"
             )
```

you'll notice that you are passing the entire dataset `subsetseg` to `dissimilarity()` for each group, which is why you are getting the same result for each county.  Given that you are using formula notation with `~`, that section should use `.x`:

```
             dissimilarity(data = .x,
                           group = "variable",
                           unit = "GEOID",
                           weight = "estimate"
             )
```

However, this operation will fail as some counties in the US are single-tract counties for which dissimilarity cannot be calculated.  So you'll want to refine your approach a bit.